# Need unix command for adding prefix

Tags: unix

I want to add a prefix `0` only for characters `[0-9]` and `[a-f]` in shell script. Is there any single line command in unix?

Example:

```
var = b f
```

Expected output:

```
var = 0b 0f
```

Comment: Try this: `for f in * ; do mv "$f" "0$f" ; done`

Comment: `sed 's/\(\b[0-9a-f]\b\)/0\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

For that rather limited test suite, you could start with `sed`:

```
$ echo 'var = b f' | sed 's/\b\([0-9a-f]\)\b/0\1/'g
var = 0b 0f
```

That finds every stand-alone lower-case hex digit (i.e., surrounded by word boundaries) and prefixes it with `0`.

Any more complex requirements may need changes to the regex but the basic idea will remain the same.